# How to use QueryDslPredicateExecutor?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, querydsl

`spring-data` offers a `QueryDslPredicateExecutor`, which imports the following statements:

```
import com.mysema.query.types.OrderSpecifier;
import com.mysema.query.types.Predicate;
```

The normal querydsl library would be:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
    <artifactId>querydsl-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.3</version>
</dependency>
```

But in order to make the spring class work, I'd have to use the following one:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
    <artifactId>querydsl-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.7.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Question: what's the difference between them, and why do I have to use a different (unofficial??) dependency?

Answer (score 0):

`com.querydsl` is the root package for Querydsl 4.* and `com.mysema.query` is the root package for Querydsl 3.*.

new versions of "spring data commons" use new root package.
[Here is link to github commit](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/commit/c013c71e7a15a63019feba5c5bf49ca63842e482)